# How do I find which packfile contains my commit/tree/blob/delta?

Tags: git

I am looking for a batteries-included solution if possible.

I ran `git cat-file -p mycommit_sha1`, then recursively done it on the trees to eventually find the sha1 of the blob of the file I am interested in.

`git unpack-file myfile_blob_sha1` works and creates the temporary file. But how does it find the blob in the packfiles :) ?

I have no multi-pack-idx in my .git/objects/pack.

Comment: Even if you have a multi-pack index, that just tells you that *a* pack file has the object, not *all* the pack files (plural) that have the object. To find all of them, you must scan them all. Note, however, that to find the hash of a blob if you know the commit and path, use `git rev-parse hash:path/to/file.ext` and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

Did it dirty with some bachism :

`for file in $(find .git/objects/pack -name '*.idx'); do git verify-pack -v "$file" | grep myblob_sha1 && echo "$file"; done`